# Subir archivos mediante selenium en un portal. C#-Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Estoy realizando un automata de uso personal utilizando selenium en Visual studio c#.

Ingreso a un portal no seguro, con mis credenciales.
Dentro del portal hay 2 secciones de mi interés, una que valida el archivo xml que deseo subir, y otro que una vez validado, puedo subir al portal.
mi idea del automata, es subir el archivo a validación, y dependiendo el mensaje de respuesta, decidir si subir en el otro apartado de subir el XML.

Sin embargo, al estar programando en c#, no logró localizar el botón para subir el archivo, a pesar de utilizar el ID,Name,clase o full xpath; he leido que es posible a que sea una aplicación aparte dentro del html, y por eso selenium no pueda leerlo y/o identificarlo. ¿como podría identificar el elemento, o que referencia extra sería necesaria para hacerlo?

```
string path = "";
                if(path=="")
                {
                    //read txt file
                    string destine = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Resources/xpath.txt";
                    path = File.ReadAllText(destine);
                }
               driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Click();     
//deseo subir un archivo, pero primero deseo hacer click para asegurar que encontro el elemento.

//info en el archivo xpath.txt
//*[@id="aaab.ValidaFacturaView.FileUploadCfd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia con mi consulta no era concretamente de los paths, ni tampoco de no poder subir los archivos, si no que en el análisis del portal, habia saltado en el código html tomar en consideración secciones que estaban en iframes. Una vez identificandolos, supe la correcta navegación y provocar los comportamientos deseados.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("navNodeAnchor_2_0")).Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("navNodeAnchor_2_0")).Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);


                
                List <IWebElement> frames = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input")));
                
                IWebElement button = null;
                foreach (IWebElement frame in frames)
                {
                    if (frame.GetAttribute("name").Equals("aaab.ValidaFacturaView.FileUploadCfd"))
                    {
                        button = frame;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                button.SendKeys(@"C:\Addendas\2020\07\16\B830440F-2803-4D03-B930-C890D1AF7C13.xml");

                List<IWebElement> sended = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")));
                foreach (IWebElement frame in sended)
                {

                    
                    if (frame.GetAttribute("id").Equals("aaab.ValidaFacturaView.ButtonCargarCFD"))
                    {
                        button = frame;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                button.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                string validacion = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/span/span/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/span/span[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span")).Text;

                if (validacion== "Factura en formato XML Aprobada")
                {
                    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("navNodeAnchor_2_2")).Click();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("navNodeAnchor_2_2")).Click();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);
                    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);



                    List<IWebElement> framesSend = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input")));

                    
                    foreach (IWebElement frame in framesSend)
                    {
                        if (frame.GetAttribute("name").Equals("aaab.IngresaFacturaView.FileUploadCfd"))
                        {
                            button = frame;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    button.SendKeys(@"C:\Addendas\2020\07\16\B830440F-2803-4D03-B930-C890D1AF7C13.xml");

                    List<IWebElement> upload = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")));
                    foreach (IWebElement frame in upload)
                    {


                        if (frame.GetAttribute("id").Equals("aaab.IngresaFacturaView.ButtonCargarCFD"))
                        {
                            button = frame;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    button.Click();
```